# How can I send fake clicks, but not detect the fake clicks

Tags: java, awtrobot

I'm trying to figure out how I can hold left click on my mouse and send fake clicks, then when I release my mouse stop sending fake clicks, but what happens when I try to do this is; I hold down my mouse, I start sending clicks with java, but when I release the fake click with java it gets detected as a real click and triggers the released function.

```
java.util.Timer task = new java.util.Timer();
public java.util.Timer t;
public void nativeMousePressed(NativeMouseEvent event)
{
    {
        if(t == null)
        {
            t = new java.util.Timer();
        }
        t.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                robot.delay(5);
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                System.out.println("False click sent" + "!");
                task.cancel();
            }
        },100,1000);
    }

}
public static boolean Released = false;
public void nativeMouseReleased(NativeMouseEvent event)
{
    t.cancel();
}
```

Comment: what is fake clicks? `robot` produces clicks which are same as mouse click for the OS. It's the whole point of `robot` -- to emulate mouse clicks.

Comment: Sorry, I should of made myself more clear. I'm looking for a way to send a click to the OS and not trigger a release event. The problem I'm running into is that when I send the robot click it detects it and triggers the mouse released event. I'm trying to figure out a way to release the mouse using a robot but not trigger the mouse released event.